# Is it possible to set standard output in Java both to a file and to the standard output?

Tags: java, redirectstandardoutput

There is a Java command to redirect standard output to a file or back to the 
 standart output:

```
PrintStream stdout = System.out;
System.setOut(new PrintStream(logFile));
// ...
System.setOut(stdout);
```

But I need to have both of them. Is it possible to set standard output in Java both to the file and to the standard output?

Comment: You can use a logger for doing this. Take a look at Apache log4j

Comment: One might also opt to handle this at the shell level using `tee` or similar.  For example, `java MyApp | tee logfile.txt`.  See https://12factor.net/logs for further thoughts on logging to file vs stdout.

Comment: @GhostCat , my question already has an answer (see duplicate question's answer). I used that solution: TeeOutputStream from Apache Commons

Comment: @GhostCat , I have used the solution: TeeOutputStream from Apache Commons (see duplicate question's answer)

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a standard class doing that, but it is pretty simple:

- first fetch the "ordinary" `stdout` PrintStream
- write your own PrintStream implementation that writes to a file *and* to another Printstream
- simply pass the original `stdout` to your new DoublePrintingPrintStream, and use `setOut()` to use that "double printing" stream

Alternatively, there are tools such as [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) that can do that for you. So instead of bothering your Java code with that - simply have something *outside* read stdout, print to console and write to a file.

Answer (score -1):

Use a **Logger**. If needed with a **Layout** just giving the input.
Then you can, even in code add both a **ConsoleAppender** and a **FileAppender**.

Also better code style. And that "logFile" is telling.